# Why is my players arcade physics body not updating touching? Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have been messing around with Phaser 3 for a couple weeks now. So when it comes to it I am very new to it.

So I am working on a Pokemon(gen I - III) inspired game. I am currently working on player movement and collisions. So being a tile based, top down game I need to check for player collisions on 4 sides of the player and this is where my problem is.

In my scene I define a player using:

`this.player = this.add.existing(new TestPlayer(this, 0, 0, "player"));`

TestPlayer is a custom class that extends `Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite` and just holds some variables related to movement. It has no methods, other than those inherited.

I make a couple of trees I want to block the player.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    this.trees[i] = this.add.existing(new Tree(this, 0, 64 + (i * 32), "tree"));
}

this.physics.add.group(this.trees, {name: 'trees'});
```

Tree is also a custom class like TestPlayer, it extends `Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite`. It does not have any methods but those inherited.

I noticed that at this point they have no physics bodies. So I enabled them using:

```
this.physics.world.enable(this.player);
this.physics.world.enable(this.trees);
```

I use `this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.trees, this.collideCallback, null, this)` to set the callback. The callback just runs `console.log(this.player.body.touching);`

I also have a simple `console.log(this.player.body.touching)` in the update method.

In both console.log cases they return `{none:true, up:false, down:false, left:false, right:false}` Why are they not updating. I would like to be able to use these to determine which directions to not allow when I parse the keys for movements. Am I going about this the right way?